# How to find the non-zero minimum value in the objective function of a mathematical model

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, mathematical-expressions

It is a mathematical model. *x* is the 0-1 decision variable, and *c* is Non-negative coefficients. The tricky problem I'm facing now is how to find that non-zero minimum value in a series of *cx*. The objective function is as follows.

[image]

Now, I want to find the minimum element in this equation which means the minimum number (*c*) selected by decision virables (*x*). However, when an element is not selected, *cx* for this element equals 0. Because *c*>0, then, the objective function equals 0. That's not what I want.

How to modify this objective function? Adding variables, non-linearity are allowed. I hope to solve this problem with **gurobi**. How to deal with the modified fuction for gurobi? (Linearization? Gurobi's built-in functions?)

Thanks!

Comment: Is this part of a larger model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce an auxiliary continuous variable `Zi` for every binary decision variable `Xi`.

Then add constraints for all `Zi`:

```
Zi = Xi * Ci + (1-Xi) * BIG_NUMBER
```

Due to this constraint, `Zi` is either `Ci` or `BIG_NUMBER`.
You can then take the minimum of all `Zi` as your objective.

Have a look at [this article](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414392016529-How-do-I-model-conditional-statements-in-Gurobi-) about conditional statements and indicator constraints.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```py
def find_non_zero_minimum(cs, xs):
    options = [ c*x for c,x in zip(cs,xs)]
    options.sort()
    return next(filter(None, options)) # return first (smallest element) after filtering out zeros
```